# How to define a custom grant type in a Spring Security Oauth2 client?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-saml, spring-session

I have a working **api-gateway** application built on **spring-boot 2.2**, which is an **Oauth2 client** supporting **authorization-code grant** flow. It is built using **spring-boot @EnableOAuth2Sso**, which will create a spring session and oauth2 context once the user is successfully logs in. Every request to the resource server will be intercepted by this api-gateway, and validates the user session also the oauth2 token from the session context. All the resource servers are Oauth2 protected.

I need to support **SAML2 login** also through this gateway. I have setup **WSO2 as Identity provider**, which provides the **SAML response as a POST request** to an endpoint in the api-gateway once a user is successfully logged in through an IDP initiated login flow. Right now the WSO2 IDP is able to provide me an **Oauth2 token when I submit a token request with SAML assertion** and SAML grant type. What I need is when a SAML POST request comes from the WSO2 IDP to the api-gateway, it should create an Oauth2 token from WSO2 using SAML assertion and SAML grant type, also should **create a Spring session and Oauth2 context** with this received Oauth2 token.

I have two possible options at this moment,

1) Define a custom spring security Oauth2 grant-type in the api-gateway Oauth2 client, and handle the SAML response to generate Oauth2 token using spring-security, also the Spring session and Oauth2 context.

2) Manually write code to generate Oauth2 token using SAML response, also manually create a new Spring session and Oauth2 context, which will be an ugly approach.

Given below the current security configuration class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class OAuth2LoginSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String ROOT_PATH = "/";
    private static final String SUFFIX = "**";
    private static final String ANY_OTHER = "/webjars";

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .antMatcher(ROOT_PATH + SUFFIX)
            .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers(LOGIN_PATH.value() + SUFFIX, ERROR_PATH.value() + SUFFIX, ANY_OTHER + SUFFIX, "/saml**").permitAll()
              .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/saml**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
              .authenticated()
            .and().csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/saml**")
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl(LOGOUT_SUCCESS_PATH.value()).permitAll();

        }

        @Bean
        public OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext clientContext, OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resourceDetails) {
            return new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails, clientContext);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
        @Bean
        public FilterRegistrationBean oauth2ClientFilterRedirectRegistration(OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
          FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
          registration.setFilter(filter);
          registration.setOrder(-100);
          return registration;
        }
}
```

The Yml configuration is given below

```
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: xxxx
      clientSecret: xxxxx
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:9763/oauth2/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:9763/oauth2/authorize
      scope: openid,email,name
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:9763/oauth2/userinfo
      jwk: 
        key-set-uri: http://localhost:9763/oauth2/jwks
```

Can someone suggest how we can define a custom spring security Oauth2 grant-type in a Oauth2 client? Is there any documentation available to configure the same? Does the spring-security support this requirement?

Also is there any other solutions to handle this scenario? Any suggestions please.

Comment: Also  is it possible to create a spring oauth session with the SAML assertion?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?